# Replace function in VBA

Tags: strings, vba

For reasons I'd rather like to not talk about, I am in a VBA environment that doesn't have the replace function (Access 97). I have wrote this to alleviate my frustrations.

My question is,  what is the quickest and most efficient way of writing this function? I am not married to it, I just want the best possible piece of code. While I do enjoy readability I am also OK with stepping away from that to learn something super cool.

```
Public Function RepStr(InputString As String, InvalidStr As String, ValidStr As String) As String
    Dim ModString As String

    ModString = InputString

    While InStr(1, ModString, InvalidStr) > 0
        ModString = Left(ModString, InStr(1, ModString, InvalidStr) - 1) & _
        ValidStr & Mid(ModString, Len(InvalidStr) + InStr(1, ModString, InvalidStr))
    Wend
    RepStr = ModString
End Function
```

Comment: Microsoft published an article (now only available via archive.org) [How To Simulate Visual Basic 6.0 String Functions in VB5](https://web.archive.org/web/20120305103750/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188007) which provides VBA5 code for `Replace`, `InStrRev`, `StrReverse`, `Join` and `Split`.

Comment: Whatever you end up using, I'd recommend mirroring the name and arguments and return type of the VB6 `Replace` function, so that when you *eventually* migrate from Access 97, you can just delete your shadowing functions, and fall back to the built-in functions. Of course, if you haven't upgraded from Access 97 *yet*, I suppose you're unlikely to do so in the foreseeable future. Maybe I shouldn't have linked to those functions? Maybe I'm giving you one less reason to upgrade?

Comment: @ThunderFrame not my choice on the upgrade unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit faster

---

```
Public Function RepStr2(txt As String, str1 As String, str2 As String) As String

    RepStr2 = Join(Split(txt, str1), str2)

End Function
```

---

Light testing with about 300K cells in col A, output in col B:

`RepStr2(CStr(arr(i, 1)), "a", "x")`

```
Col A          | Col B
abcabcabc      | xbcxbcxbc
aaa            | xxx
aaaaaaaaa      | xxxxxxxxx
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa | xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
... (duplicated down to 300K)
```

After repeated tests all functions run faster

> ```
> Your version: 2.039 secs
> This version: 1.406 secs
> MS version:   1.688 secs (bellow)
> ```

---

**Edit** (as pointed out by [ThunderFrame](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/94097/thunderframe) in the comment)

Microsoft's version is fast as well:

```
Public Function RepStr3(sIn As String, sFind As String, sReplace As String, _
                        Optional nStart As Long = 1, Optional nCount As Long = -1, _
                        Optional bCompare As VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare) As String

    Dim nC As Long, nPos As Integer, sOut As String

    sOut = sIn
    nPos = InStr(nStart, sOut, sFind, bCompare)

    If nPos = 0 Then GoTo EndFn:

    Do
        nC = nC + 1
        sOut = Left(sOut, nPos - 1) & sReplace & Mid(sOut, nPos + Len(sFind))

        If nCount <> -1 And nC >= nCount Then Exit Do

        nPos = InStr(nStart, sOut, sFind, bCompare)

    Loop While nPos > 0

EndFn:

    RepStr3 = sOut

End Function
```

Comment: That's nice, except it's VBA5, and the `Join` function doesn't exist either.

Comment: I was about to say, it would be nice if certain things were actually availble to this project.

Comment: Come to think of it, `Split` wasn't in VB5 either. See my comment on original question with link to MS KB article that offers code for the missing string functions.

Comment: Good call: MS is the fastest option - I'll update the answer